# LINQ to XML LIKE clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, traversal

Given the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Message>
      <ArrayOfStock xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <Stock>
                  <StockID>9cddb639-25ee-4415-be07-3109e5ae9883</StockID>
                  <Description>Stock Item 0</Description>
            </Stock>
            <Stock>
                  <StockID>f89f02f9-b359-48c8-8d2f-3a950837f4fb</StockID>
                  <Description>Stock Item 1</Description>
            </Stock>
            <Stock>
                  <StockID>3338ec80-f59e-4979-a04c-f7d52e386bb7</StockID>
                  <Description>Stock Item 2</Description>
            </Stock>
      </ArrayOfStock>
</Message>
```

Is there a better/more correct way to return children of Message WHERE the childrens names start with "ArrayOf" then this?

```
IEnumerable<XElement> array = from arrayOfX 
                              in document.Root.Elements() 
                              where arrayOfX.Name.ToString().IndexOf("ArrayOf") > -1
                              select arrayOfX;
```

PS: This also has an issue for the edge case where IndexOf() will return 0 for a String.Empty value. (Although not sure if thats actually possible in well formatted XML - dont think it is?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`String.StartsWith()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx)?

Comment: Ummmm. Well now I feel like a goose... Forgot about that method.

Comment: There are lots of useful `String` methods in .NET (`Contains`, `StartsWith`, `EndsWith` to name but three) - learn them!

Answer (score 0):

A better way to return objects that model the xml structure? Yes.  Create a class that models the xml structure, and serialize the xml as such:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("ArrayOfStocks")]
public class Stocks 
{     
    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(Stock))]     
    public Stock[] Stocks { get; set; }  
}
public class Stock
{
    public StockID { get; set; }

    public Description { get; set; }
}
    public class Message
    {
        public Stocks { get; set; }

        public static Message Load( string xml )
        {
                var deserializer = new XmlSerializer( typeof( Stocks ) );
                Stocks stocks = null;
                using( TextReader textReader = new StringReader( data ) )
                {
                    stocks = (Stocks)deserializer.Deserialize( textReader );
                }

                return stocks;
        }
    }
```

Then you can access the array of stocks by:

```
var message = Message.Load( "<xml>" );
foreach( var stock in message.Stocks )
{
   Console.WriteLine( stock );
}
```

Then, in your 'edge case', you won't have to worry about it.  The Stocks array will simply be empt.

Comment: Appreciate the advice but unfortunately in my case this doesn't work. The XML I am parsing is completely arbitrary and I have no way of knowing its structure I simply provided stock as an example.

Comment: I see. np.  The key word there is arbitrary, which was not clear to me from the OP